# How to use absolute position for touch event using AirTest (Orientation doesn't matter)

Tags: android, python, adb

I have a script that parses the output of the `adb shell getevent -t` command into more abstract events (e.g. `Type: LONG_CLICK, Location: (x, y)`). I use this parsed output to replay the events that  happed during the `adb` command using the AirTest mobile game testing framework, using mainly only their android api. One example would be running the AirTest command `touch((x,y))`, however, the AirTest `touch` command takes into account the orientation of the device while `adb shell getevent -t` does not. This causes a mismatch between the two coordinate systems and undesired behaviour. I am wondering is there a way to either make the `adb` command give relative coordinates based on the orientation of the device or is there a way to make AirTest ignore the orientation of the device. I've looked through the android documentation on the `[getevent][1]` command for `adb`, but it did not talk about any flags that could do this. I've been through AirTests [documentation](https://airtest.readthedocs.io/en/latest/all_module/airtest.core.api.html) as well and there was no non-hacky way to do this. The hacky way I found was going into the source code for the library and comment out the section that performs the translation depending on the orientation, however, this is undesired since it is not practical to have to change the source code of the library to get this behaviour.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out. I can just directly change what AirTest thinks the orientation is before I perform the touch command:

```
android = api.device()
android._display_info["orientation"] = 0.0
```

Which sets the orientation value to 0.0 which uses the same coordinate system as `adb shell getevent -t`